# Bokeh DataTable not updating row height since version 1.0.4

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm using bokeh datable table to display a pandas dataframe and the display is wrong. For some reason, the cell text is being pushed down in each cell. The behaviour is fine in v.1.0.4 but since then it appears.

The code is:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter

example_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'x':[0]*6, 
         'y':[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         'color':['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'green']})
source = ColumnDataSource(example_df)

template="""
            <p style="font-size:18px;
                color:<%= 
                (function colorfromint(){
                    if (color == 'green')
                        {return('green')}
                    }()) %>;"> 
                <%= value %>
            </p>
         """

formatter =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="x", formatter=formatter,
                    title='<p style="font-size:160%;"> Field 1 </p>'),
        TableColumn(field="y", formatter=formatter, 
                    title='<p style="font-size:160%;"> Field 2 </p>'),
    ]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=1200, height=800, index_position = None)

show(data_table)
```

The wrong output is
[image: Table using bokeh v1.0.4]

while the correct ouput is
[image: Behaviour after v1.0.4]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works with the `<p>` elements replaced by `<span>` elements.

```
template="""
<span style="font-size:18px;
    color:<%=
    (function colorfromint(){
        if (color == 'green')
            {return('green')}
        }()) %>;">
    <%= value %>
</span>
"""

formatter =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", formatter=formatter,
                title='<span style="font-size:160%;"> Field 1 </span>'),
    TableColumn(field="y", formatter=formatter,
                title='<span style="font-size:160%;"> Field 2 </span>'),
]
```

[image]

I'm not certain what's at the root of the style changes, but I would regard `<span>` as the better choice here in any case.